# How to make a copy file succeed even if files are not present in TFS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Need your help on TFS build for one of my apps 
I have a copy file task in my build which copies the file from SourceFolder`$(Build.SourceDirectory)/DataBase/Scripts` to targetFolder `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/DataBase/Scripts`.

This works fine if scripts are present in the Source location but fails when there are no files. I need my build to succeed in any case, even if files are not present.

Comment: yes. I did , Actually i then created a powershell script and its working after that . Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Nilesh Chaturvedi,Would you please share your solution as an answer for this issue? So it would help other community members who get the same issue as your find the solution easily. Thanks for your sharing.

Answer (score 2):

you could use `continueOnError` on that particular build step and set it to true so it doesnt cause the job to fail if it fails.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#steps

Answer (score 2):

If no files in Source Folder `Scripts`, the task will still report success. If the Source Folder `Scripts` doesn't exist, the task will report fail as build agent can not find the folder. This is an expected behavior, if the source folder doesn't exist and it reports success, you'll get incorrect result if you type wrong folder name.